# Is there a working nodejs/phantomjs Heroku buildpack?

Tags: heroku, phantomjs, buildpack

I'd like to deploy an app with a Procfile that runs

```
web: node myapp.js
```

Where myapp.js uses `phantomjs-node` to run headless webkit stuff, returning the results to  browser requests. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku Toolbelt [now has first class support for multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/653), so you can get a working Node and PhantomJS setup with the following:

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git`

`heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git`

Answer (score 30):

I also ran into the same problem, the way I fixed it was by using this ["Multiple Buildpack" Buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi). Then in my .buildpacks file I put the following:

```
http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

Finally, you want to add PhantomJS to the path

```
heroku config:set PATH=$PATH:vendor/phantomjs/bin
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had to change http to https or else it would hang on first trying to push.

Comment: Heya, by <prev PATH> - where do u mean? node_modules/phantom ?

Comment: I meant like `$PATH` should I edit the answer? Is that confusing?

Comment: It works but need to fix protocol from http to https in the contents of .buildpacks file

Comment: Multiple Buildpack Buildpack is now deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Here's a PhantomJS buildpack: https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs

I also am able to run the x86_64 build of PhamtomJS, just stuck in my app's `vendor` directory:

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: The linked buildpack only has PhantomJS, no nodejs. Regarding your second answer: Are you saying I can use the normal node.js buildpack, and place phantomjs in my app's `vendor` directory, using it that way? (I'm unable to test on my own atm)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout my modified version of stomita that includes NodeJS, PhantomJS & CasperJS ready to run.
    https://github.com/olragon/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but for anybody that lands here I have created a working buildpack for Node and Phantom that's a fork of the official Heroku Node buildpack which incorporates the build scripts from [Beedesk's custom Phantom buildpack](https://github.com/beedesk/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs). Here it is https://github.com/datamail/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

I have forked @stomita buildpack to use the official linux build binary from phantomJS.org. I tested it and it is working with heroku.

Hope some security paranoids like me out there will find it useful.

https://github.com/beedesk/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs

The disadvantage of my pack it that, unlike stomita's, it doesn't include `fontconfig` and `freetype`. But, PhantomJS should work without them.

Comment: @stomita was kind enough to look at my pull request and merged it in. So, you can have phantomJS buildpack that depends on the official build.