# Heroku "Multiple Buildpack" Buildpack not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs, buildpack

My app depends on both nodejs and phantomjs and I follow the trigoman's answer of [Is there a working nodejs/phantomjs Heroku buildpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607209/is-there-a-working-nodejs-phantomjs-heroku-buildpack).

But I got stucked as follows:

```
creating young-thicket-8895... done, region is us
BUILDPACK_URL=http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
http://young-thicket-8895.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:young-thicket-8895.git
Git remote heroku added
Setting config vars and restarting young-thicket-8895... done, v4
PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/vendor/phantomjs/bin
Setting config vars and restarting young-thicket-8895... done, v5
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/app/vendor/phantomjs/lib
Counting objects: 26, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 22.00 KiB, done.
Total 26 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
```

The process stops for quite a lot time and then

```
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

Comment: What's the contents of your `.buildpacks` file?

Comment: @dankoh http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi/issues/16 -- change the buildpacks to point to the `https://` git repo url. instead of `http://` or `git://`

Works for me.