# Unable to find phantomjs executable on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, phantomjs, watir, buildpack

I am using gem Watir in my web application. When my user triggers an action the watir webdriver is opened and there's scrapping and posting on websites involved. I dont want my users to see the browser during the action so I am using watir with a ghostdriver using phantomJS as is explained here : http://watirmelon.com/2013/02/05/watir-webdriver-with-ghostdriver-on-osx-headless-browser-testing/
This works perfectly locally, however when I try using it on heroku deploy I get the following error:

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError (Unable to find phantomjs executable.):
```

Then I tried to add nodeJS & phantomJS buildpack as specified here
[Is there a working nodejs/phantomjs Heroku buildpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607209/is-there-a-working-nodejs-phantomjs-heroku-buildpack)
I ran the following command line in the console :

```
➜  tennis-match git:(master) heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git --app we-tennis-staging
Buildpack set. Next release on we-tennis-staging will use https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git.
Run `git push heroku master` to create a new release using this buildpack.
➜  tennis-match git:(master) heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git --app we-tennis-staging
Buildpack added. Next release on we-tennis-staging will use:
  1. https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
  2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
Run `git push heroku master` to create a new release using these buildpacks.
```

then pushed on my staging app

```
➜  tennis-match git:(master) git push staging master                                                 
Everything up-to-date
```

But I still get the error. Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: did u happen to find a fix?

Comment: nope no fix, had to go all the way with mechanize

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

https://gist.github.com/edelpero/9257311

**Note:** After following the above instructions, make sure you have a Procfile with the code mentioned below:

```
web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
```